# How to display an avatar/thumbnail picture after uploading it in Vue js (Element-ui)?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui, photo-upload

I am currently working on uploading a picture and displaying it as a thumbnail or as an avatar after uploading it. I have written the below code. It successfully uploads it but I am having trouble displaying it in place of the uploader.

```
                      <el-upload
                        class="styling-photo"
                        ref="upload"
                        action="#"
                        :auto-upload="false"
                        :show-file-list="true"
                        :on-success="handleAvatarSuccess"
                        > 
                        <img v-if="file" :src="file" alt="">
                          <i v-else class="abc"></i>
                      </el-upload>
```

In the image below, I have uploaded the pic.jpg picture, but unable to display it after uploading it.
Can someone help me with this? Working on this issue from sometime.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the "handleAvatarSuccess" function as well to the question to get a better understanding?

Comment: handleAvatarSuccess(res, file) {
        this.imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file.raw);
      },

This is the "handleAvatarSuccess" function. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. can you also add the html code block of the `image display` to your question. so that I can give you a definite answer based on your actual implementation

Answer (score 0):

Going by the contents of handleAvatarSuccess, it seems it sets an imageUrl property. I think you need to use that imageUrl as the :src property.

```
<img v-if="file" :src="imageUrl" alt="">
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to check if the `file` property is set anywhere or change that to imageUrl as well.

Comment: The above solution does not work. Changing the file property to imageURL does not work either. Also, I am trying to upload and display the image on a dialog box. Does displaying on a dialog be anything different than doing it not on a dialog box?